# C# problems getting results from List<T> BinarySearch with duplicates in the first and last position

Tags: c#, binary-search

I'm playing around with different implementations for the most simple of the LeetCode problems TwoSums. I have various other ways working fine using methods like indexof, Dictionary searches, brute force, etc... and my best so far is better than 98.67% using List.IndexOf

I'm trying to implement a version with BinarySearch for comparison. It passes most tests but seems to fail when needing to sum duplicates in the first and last position and the list length is gt 2. I'm sure there are other fail conditions but I can't get past this one.

When stepping through the code it returns a negative number instead of the index when the last and first are the same value despite starting at i+1 index location.

I have to be missing something obvious but I'm just not seeing it for some reason. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding how BinarySearch works with index and length.

These pass:
{ 0, 2, 3 } target 3
result: {0, 2}

{ 3, 3 } target 6
result: { 0, 1 }

{ 0, 2, 0, 3 } target 0
result: { 0, 2 }

These fail:
{ 0, 2, 0 } target 0
expected: { 0, 2 }
result: null

{ 1, 4, 1 } target 2
expected: { 0, 2 }
result: null

The code sample is verbose for now while I'm working through the issues. I'll minimize it later.

offset is used to start the search at an index higher than i
subsetLength is used to keep the search length from going outside the bounds
The n > i is just a sanity check to make sure n is a higher index value than i before returning a valid result

```
public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
{
    List<int> numList = new List<int>(nums);
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        int offset = i + 1; 
        int subsetLength = nums.Length - offset; 
        int searchNum = target - nums[i]; 
        int n = numList.BinarySearch(offset, subsetLength, searchNum, null);
        if (n > i) 
            return new int[] { i, n };
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Binary search only works when the list is already sorted. Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-binarysearch(system-int32-system-int32-0-system-collections-generic-icomparer((-0)))): "The `List<T>` must already be sorted according to the comparer implementation; otherwise, the result is incorrect."

Comment: I'll admit I've not used BinarySearch before and I did see that in the documentation. I'll surrender that I'm probably using it wrong but it was promising when I was getting successful results from the likes of { 0, 2, 0, 3 }, I was just looking for something faster than IndexOf and this looked promising.

Comment: It's still quicker than `O(N²)` to sort it first: Sorting would take `O(N.Log(N))` and the binary search loop part would take `O(N.Log(N))` too, which works out to `O(N.Log(N))` overall - and that's faster than `O(N²)` . (The loop complexity is from having to do a binary search `O(Log(N))` for `N/2` iterations.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a special case `target / 2 + target / 2 == target` when you check for *two* items each of which are `target / 2`:

```
public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
  // Comment out if nums is already sorted
  Array.Sort(nums);

  for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; ++i) {
    int item = nums[i];
    int toFind = target - item;

    if (toFind < nums[i])
      break;

    int index = Array.BinarySearch(nums, toFind);

    if (index >= 0) {
      if (toFind == item) {
        // Special case: two equal numbers: target / 2 + target / 2 = target
        if (i < nums.Length - 1 && nums[i] == nums[i + 1])
          return new int[] { i, i + 1 };

        break;
      }
      else
        return new int[] { i, index };
    }
  }

  return new int[] { -1, -1 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the list before searching it:

```
public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
    {
        List<int> numList = new List<int>(nums);

        numList.Sort();

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            int offset = i + 1;
            int subsetLength = nums.Length - offset;
            int searchNum = target - nums[i];
            int n = numList.BinarySearch(offset, subsetLength, searchNum, null);
            if (n > i)
                return new int[] { i, n };
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: The problem with sorting is then I lose the original index position which is the goal. So in the case of { 0, 3, 4, 0 } it sorts to { 0, 0, 3, 4 } and the returned results end up being { 0, 1 } instead of { 0, 4 }